# Is there a way to dynamically wrap two elements into a div IF they exist?

Tags: html, css

I have an Angular application that renders spans based on whether they're needed or not (many ng-if's). I need to wrap these spans in a div based on their content/class names.

So, for example:

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
```

I don't want to do anything. But with

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
<div class="4"></div>
```

I DO want to wrap these 4 divs in a parent div `<div class="parent"></div>`, but only if the four appear one after the other. Is there a way to do this in CSS? Can I just use a combo of selectors to manipulate the four elements if they appear consecutively?

Comment: _“Is there a way to do this in CSS?”_ – of course there isn’t; CSS can not create new structural HTML elements, that is totally not the part of the duties of CSS … But since this is an Angular app anyway, why don’t you just do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Show us the angular templates.

Comment: **absolutely** not in **css** but you can do it in _jQuery_ by calculating the number of classes and wrapping them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you cant do this using just css and html, like the comments above, you need to use some form of javascript to manipulate the dom.  heres an example using jQuery. hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrapme').each(function() {
        var myElement = $(this);
        var next1 = $(this).next();
        var next2 = $(this).next().next();
        var next3 = $(this).next().next().next();
        if (next1.hasClass('wrapme') && next2.hasClass('wrapme') && next3.hasClass('wrapme')) {
            var html = '<div class="parent"></div>';
            next3.after(html);
            var parent = next3.next('.parent')
            parent.append(myElement);
            parent.append(next1);
            parent.append(next2);
            parent.append(next3);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapme">1</div>
<div class="wrapme">2</div>
<div class="wrapme">3</div>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
<div class="wrapme">1</div>
<div class="wrapme">2</div>
<div class="wrapme">3</div>
<div class="wrapme">4</div>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
<div class="wrapme">1</div>
<div class="wrapme">2<div>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
<div class="wrapme">1</div>
<div class="wrapme">2</div>
<div class="wrapme">3</div>
<div class="wrapme">4</div>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
<div class="wrapme">1</div>
<div class="wrapme">2</div>
    <a href=""> hey hey</a>
<div class="wrapme">3</div>
<div class="wrapme">4</div>
<span>BREAKKKKKK</span>
```